# Pass args to bash script from git using curl

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I'm looking for ways to pass arguments to a script fetched from git using curl, and my script requires an argument.
Is there any way that arguments can be passed to script as following:

```
bash <(curl -Ls <git-script-path>)
```

Script usage: `./script.sh -p admin`. I am trying to provide `-p admin` as  `bash <(curl -Ls <git-script-path>) -p admin`

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: will you illustrate a little bit what actually you needed ?

Comment: Scenario is, script reads interactive input as well as cmd line input, i want both to work with, such that I'll pass my cmd line arg to  bash <(curl -Ls <git-script-path>) & after it runs, it will also ask for interactive arguments from user. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I would suggest you to call it  by creating a main.sh script embedded this in that it would be better ...!!!

Comment: Could you tell us how `bash <(curl -Ls <git-script-path>) -p admin` failed to do what you needed it to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
curl -Ls <git-script-path> | bash -s -- -p admin
```

This causes `bash` to read the shell commands from its standard input stream, which is connected to `curl`.  The `-p` and `admin` are the two arguments that will be accessible as the positional parameters in the script.  The `--` is needed to signal the end of options for the `bash` executable.

Testing with a one-line script in `script.sh` which *only* does `printf '"%s"\n' "$@"` (outputs its command line arguments, quoted, on separate lines).  We'll let `cat script.sh` be a stand-in for your `curl` command:

```
$ cat script.sh| bash -s -- -p admin
"-p"
"admin"
```

If your script requires interactivity, you can't read the script itself from standard input.  Instead, provide the script via a filename:

```
$ bash <( curl -Ls <git-script-path> ) -p admin
```

This happens to be exactly what you have in your question.  Note that this requires the current shell to understand process substitutions using `<( ... )`.

Comment: Scenario is, script reads interactive input as well as cmd line input, i want both to work with, such that First I'll pass my cmd line arg to `bash <(curl -Ls <git-script-path>) ` & after it runs, it will also ask for interactive arguments from user. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: @usergg123 See Pankis answer.   Ideally, these requirements should have been mentioned in the question.

Comment: @usergg123 See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in separate steps. First, get the script and place it in a file:

```
curl -sL https://...git > script.sh
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

And execute with params:

```
./script.sh -p admin
```

As a oneliner:

```
curl -sL https://...git > script.sh && chmod +x script.sh && ./script.sh -p admin
```

If you don't want to store the script permanently, you could do

```
tmpFile=$(mktemp) && curl -sL https://...git > $tmpFile && chmod +x $tmpFile && $tmpFile -p admin && rm $tmpFile
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass arguments to the script, just add them to the command line:

```
bash <(curl -Ls <git-script-path>) -p admin
```

Example with command to just display the arguments:

```
$ bash <(echo 'echo args: "$@"') -p admin
args: -p admin
```

Comment: it worked, thanks!